# To get value of textbox in a variable within singlequotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

Following is my view page,

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
     }
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var date = $('#test').val();
    $('#test').datepicker({
        defaultDate: date
    }).datepicker('setDate', date);
    });
   </script>
    <input type="text" id="test" name="Date" value='22/12/2013' />
```

I'm getting the date value in double quotes in date variable I want to get it in single quotes how can I get the date value in single quotes into the date variable using jQuery?

Comment: can you tell us what you are trying to do...

Comment: How does get it in single quotes make any difference?

Comment: What are you talking about, value is not wrapped inside quotes: http://jsfiddle.net/9bcyh/

Comment: string literals can be enclosed within `''` or `""` it doesn't matter

Comment: please explain why you want value to be in **' '** it doesnt really matter ..

Comment: ya then ly the datepicker accepts the date value..

Comment: i want to pass it that value inside the datepicker jquery..that's why..

Comment: @user2514925 and what about reading the DOC. Your issue is a typical XY issue... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I think the best you can do is call the datepicker over the text box and set the default value to the text box externally.`$( "#test" ).datepicker(); $(#test).val('22/12/2013')` . the code is quite simpler in this case

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the date format(the default format is `mm/dd/yy`)... set it using [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = $('#test').val();
    $('#test').datepicker({
        defaultDate: date,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    }).datepicker('setDate', date);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m53tA/)